# Как создать 2 ветки в git из одной без потери данных

Tags: git, git-branch

Такой вопрос, есть одна ветка с изменениями ... на ее основе нужно сделать 2 ветки, первая будет в себе содержать скрипт генерации, а во  второй изменения для фронта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если изменения не закоммичены. Допустим рабочая ветка master и из неё надо создать ветки.

```
git checkout -b generated_files
git add <список файлов через пробел для генерации>
git commit -m "файлы генерации"

git checkout master
git checkout -b frontend
git add .
git commit -m "файлы фронта"
```

Comment: Всё верно, только обращу внимание на то, что в результате получатся 3 ветки. Возможно, автор имел в виду просто деление одной ветки на две, но правильно именно делать две новых ветки (1 под каждую фичу), а потом в `master` сливать оттестированные фичи.